# Tripwire noticed this change but I'm not sure what it means?

Tags: windows-server-2008

The following change was noticed on several Windows 2008 R2 servers.  The change relates to the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\COMPONENTS{016888b8-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}TxR.2.regtrans-ms
```

This item was removed.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [transactional registry file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303705.aspx). This is a reliability feature that was added in Windows Vista. For the most part, Windows just handles these files on its own and you shouldn't need to deal with them. It looks like you did a Tripwire scan while there was a temporary `.regtrans-ms` file present and now it's gone. It's nothing to be worried about, though I'm not familiar enough with Tripwire to tell you how to ignore it in future scans.

Comment: I will look in to the transactional registry files -thanks-